# Cant send e-mail with C# on unity , windows build

Tags: c#, email, gmail, unity-game-engine

Im using unity, to send an email with a screenshot to my email,
it works perfectly with the debugger but, when i build the standalone, it doesn't work anyway...
heres my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class Tabela : MonoBehaviour 
{

   public void OnGUI()
    {
            {
                StartCoroutine(ScreenshotEncode());
            }
    }

    IEnumerator ScreenshotEncode()
    {
        // We should only read the screen after all rendering is complete
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D( width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
        // Read screen contents into the texture
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0 );
        tex.Apply();

        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();

        // save our test image (could also upload to WWW)
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../test-" + count + ".png", bytes);
       // count++;

        DestroyObject(tex);

        Debug.Log(Application.dataPath + "/../test-" + count + ".png");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Teste ";
        mail.Body = "test";

        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Application.dataPath + "/../test-" + count + ".png",
                                            @"image/png"));

        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpServer.Port = 587;
        smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password") as ICredentialsByHost;
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
        {
            return true; 
        };
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        Debug.Log("success");
        status = "ok";
    }
}
```

/=============== EDIT ===========
Got some error :

```
smtpexception: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257g26sm76791788yhk.3 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Side note: I don't see any DI-friendly code... Are you sure "unity" tag is correct? Maybe "unity3d"...

Comment: I would verify your `Application.dataPath` is what you expect it to be  when running outside the debugger. Just a shot in the dark, but if it can't find the folder, an exception will be thrown and I don't see any error handling.

Comment: @Grant Winney edited for the error im getting

Answer (score 3):

The solution was on player settings->Other settings->api compatibility level-> .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, the smtp client (gmail) not giving permission to send it from unsecured apps, to solve this give the access for less secure apps for the gmail account you are using to send the mail.